# Wifi doesn't work on a fresh install of Lubuntu on a Beelink BT3-Pro

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, internet

I'm new to the Linux world and I've already got a problem.
The Wi-Fi connection on my mini PC (Beelink BT3-Pro) doesn't work. LAN connection works fine, but right now I can't use the Wi-Fi connection. I can "turn" it on but nothing happens. Before Lubuntu I've tried Elementary OS and I had the same problem.
**RTL8111/8168/8411** PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
That's the name of the connection board. I've read online that it has a problem with Linux. I've also tried to follow few guides but I always get errors over errors. On Windows 10 the Wi-Fi connection used to work flawless.
What can I do?
I'm on the latest Lubuntu version. Also, could you explain to me every single step? I doesn't know Linux at all, but I want to learn!

EDIT: added result for:lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; uname -r

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
6.2.0-39-generic
```

Results for lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've used the uname -r command:

```
6.2.0-39-generic
```

Results for neofetch:

```
OS: Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: BT3 Pro BT3 Pro V01 
Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic 
Uptime: 35 mins 
Packages: 1911 (dpkg), 16 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: LXQt 0.17.1 
WM: Openbox 
Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK2/3] 
Icons: ePapirus [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: qterminal 
Terminal Font: Ubuntu Mono 14 
CPU: Intel Atom x5-Z8350 (4) @ 1.920GHz 
GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8 
Memory: 2290MiB / 3831MiB
```

Thank you Guiverc, this command is so cool!

I've watched a video of a teardown and there isn't a wifi card to remove :(

Results for the command wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
chmod +x wireless-info &&
./wireless-info

https://pastebin.com/7EKw0NaL

Nothing happens if I type modprobe r8169  on the terminal

Results for sudo dmesg| grep -i firm; lsmod | grep cfg

```
[    0.162386] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.412293] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[   13.388700] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.Beelink-BT3  Pro.bin failed with error -2
[   13.402744] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt failed with error -2
[   13.421032] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   14.125299] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[   14.125319] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[   14.184441] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[   14.184460] sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
cfg80211             1241088  1 brcmfmac
```

@Jeremy **YOU ARE THE GOAT!** IT WORKS NOW!!! I'M SPEECHLESS, THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!

Comment: Edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; uname -r`

Comment: Results for `lsusb`  Is there any wifi/WLAN settings in the BIOS?

Comment: @guiverc what command can I use in order to give you the needed information?

Comment: Take the cover off, remove and reinsert the wifi card,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: What happens when you `modprobe r8169` please?

Comment: Are there any results from terminal for `sudo dmesg| grep -i firm; lsmod | grep cfg`

Comment: Try `cd /lib/firmware/brcm && sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reMarkable/brcmfmac-firmware/master/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt` reboot

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi is missing firmware, you either installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode of the firmware doesn't exist in efivars, so in terminal do

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reMarkable/brcmfmac-firmware/master/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
```

Reboot